# Case statement with "WHEN OTHERS" in code coverage analysis

Tags: vhdl

A piece of VHDL code for injecting error to input data is shown below:

```
entity error_test
Port ( 
clk           : in  STD_LOGIC;
force_error_i : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
din           : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 downto 0);
dout          : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 downto 0)
);
end error_test;

architecture Behavioral of error_test is

signal single_error_2   : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := x"00000000000000000000000000000001"; 
signal double_error_2   : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := x"00000000000000000000000000000003";
signal triple_error_2   : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := x"00000000000000000000000000000007";
signal din_errinj_2     : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);

process (force_error_i, din, single_error, double_error, triple_error)
  begin
   case (force_error_i) is 
    when "00" =>
      din_errinj_2        <= din;

    when "01" =>
      din_errinj_2        <= din xor single_error_2(127 downto 0);

    when "10" =>
      din_errinj_2        <= din xor double_error_2(127 downto 0);

    when "11" =>   
      din_errinj_2        <= din xor triple_error_2(127 downto 0);

    when others =>
      din_errinj_2        <= din;
  end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

This module works fine in the main design and also in the testbench simulation.

But the issue is with the code coverage tool analysis. The code coverage tool(Reviera-PRO from Aldec) shows that when the input *force_error_i(2)* is "00" then **when "00"** is covered and also **when others** condition is also covered! Is the **when others** condition redundant here? Or do we need others statement but something else is wrong here?

Comment: Is force_error_i(2) a std_logic_vector such that you can have metalogical values?

Comment: This sounds like a question for the vendor. In VHDL the choices are exclusive. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement para 5 "...each value of the subtype shall be represented once and only once in the set of choices of the case statement,". A work around might be to create an intermediary variable of a bit_vector of length 2 and assign the `to_bit_vector(force_error_i(2)) value to and use that as your case value. This assumes your base type is std_logic_vector.

Comment: Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're audience shouldn't have to assume any declared object type and should be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: @lasplund: I have updated the code. Please check it.

Comment: @user1155120: updated the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not redundant since you can have values like "UU". I would guess this is your problem since you're not synchronous and the process will run once initially. Not sure what counts as coverage in your simulator though.